# Write this program in python

Tags: python, function

Write a program that contains ADD and AVERAGE user defined functions. On execution your program prompts for three numbers from user and call the AVERAGE function. Send the entered three numbers to AVERAGE function. The AVERAGE function call ADD function and send the three user entered numbers to it. The ADD function accepts the numbers from AVERAGE function and calculate sum. Send this sum value back to calling point (AVERAGE function). The AVERAGE function receive the sum value and calculates average for that sum of three numbers. The AVERAGE function send the average value to its calling point (outside of both functions). At the end display the average value from outside these functions.

The output should be:

`a: 2
b: 3
c: 4
Average: 3.0`

Comment: You should set a descriptive title. Yours applies to ANY question.

Comment: 1. Your function ADD() calls function AVERAGE(), and function AVERAGE() calls ADD(). This should be avoided.<br> 2. Function AVERAGE() takes 3 arguements, when you are calling from ADD(), you are passing only 1 argument. <br> 3. At the end, you are calling ADD(), but not used anywhere so it is redundant.

Comment: Sorry but this is my first time using stackoverflow, i need the program which is telling in the question.

Comment: Hi James Bond. Can you please show us, what you tried yourself and then ask about specific problems or questions that you have encountered? This looks like you're asking for others to write your complete homework for you which is unfortunately not the idea of stackoverflow. This is where the downvotes are coming from, people are eager to help you here, but you have to show some work of your own too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def add(a,b,c):    
    return a+b+c  

def average(a,b,c):
    d = add(a,b,c)
    e = d/3
    return e

f = average(2,3,3)
print(f)
```

Output:

`f` `=` `2.6666666666666665`

Comment: @James Bond , if you want to get accurate answer then you can use `math.ceil()`

Comment: This is what i want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generic way of doing this :

```
def adder(num):
    return sum(num)

def avg(*num):
    return adder(num)/len(num)


print("Average: ",avg(1,2,3,4))
```

Now you can pass as much numbers as you want.

Comment: I need the program should be given as question.

Answer (score 0):

**The best practice tactics will solve it, like;**

```
n1 = int(input("Enter Number 1: " ))
n2 = int(input("Enter Number 2: " ))
n3 = int(input("Enter Number 3: " ))

def ADD(a,b,c):
return a+b+c  

def AVERAGE(a,b,c):
X = ADD(a,b,c)
Y = X/3
return Y

F = AVERAGE(n1, n2, n3)
print(F)
```

Good luck!

Regards: [Khairullah Hamsafar](https://bitabhamsafar.blogspot.com/)